# Threads in C programming (linux)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mutex

I have to write a program, basically a game - in short, there are soldiers(threads) that gather resources, unload recources in the base, train themselves and some other stuff. I've been reading about threads and how to use them for a solid 6-7 hours marathon already, but i think i need some help. So, i can write a very simple program with threads that use one function, lets say a function that prints "hello i am thread number:N". But, what i do not get - if for instance we look up this easy program with the print statement, we give each thread a pointer to the function and it's all fun and games. But,  in my case i have to do multiple functions and what i do not get is how can i make all the threads go through all the different functions? The main idea is to use mutexes and condvars, but as i can give each thread only one function pointer in its arguments, i do not see how can i accomplish this task, since i have like 3-4 functions. I don't think the creation of one thread for each functions solves the problem, here is why:

```
Game begins!
Worker 1 is searching
Worker 1 is transporting
Worker 1 unloaded resources to Base station
Worker 2 is searching
Worker 2 is transporting
Worker 2 unloaded resources to Base stationW
Operation not supported
Worker 3 is searching
Worker 3 is transporting
Worker 3 unloaded resources to Base station
.....
b
Not enough resources
Worker 4 is searching
Worker 4 is transporting
Worker 4 unloaded resources to Base station
...
b
Worker 3 is constructing new building barracks
Worker 2 is searching
Worker 2 is transporting
Worker 2 unloaded resources to Base station
....
Worker 3 completed new building barracks
w
Warrior is being trained
Worker 3 is searching
Warrior is ready for duty
```

this must be the output of the game. Don't mind W and B - just some operations that must meet certain conditions in order to run.
So my question is - should i use one thread for each function? I don't want you to solve my problem, i will just be very happy to enlighten me how i should approach this, thank you very much!

Comment: Modeling objects such as soldiers as threads is a really bad idea. Rethink your design.

Comment: This is my task, i have to do it that way. It is not my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread has a single function where it *starts* running, but that function can call others.  It's analogous to the `main()` function where your program's main thread starts running.

From your example output, it looks like you'll want each thread to run a loop that goes through a sequence of steps (searching, transporting, etc.) repeatedly.  Each step can involve calling one or more other functions.  And those functions can do things like block on a condition variable to wait for availability of resources.

On a related note: in addition to the function pointer, `pthread_create` only lets you pass a single `arg` pointer as data to the thread.  Assuming your thread needs more than a single pointer worth of information, you'll want to create a `struct` to hold whatever information the thread needs, and pass a pointer to that.

Comment: So basically you are saying create a thread for each function, loop until a condition is met and return some value? This makes me wanna ask, if for instance i have a gatherResources function and lets say i get 5 resources, how can  i  store this i a global variable and/or return it in to the main? as far as i know using pthread_ext(N) - where N is lets say 5 in our case, and then in the main pthread_join(threadName,[storeNhere])? Could you please explain this to me

Comment: No, I'm saying create a thread for each soldier, and have it do all the things that a soldier needs to do — which involves *calling* functions like `gatherResources` and `deliverResources`, and probably involves a loop since the solder should gather more resources after delivering the first batch.

Comment: What if i have to create soldiers? Should i just write a function for soldierCreation, use a thread for it and increment a global variable each time a soldier is created?

Comment: Creating a soldier would involve starting a thread. The specifics of where you do that in your code, and how you keep track of the soldiers you've created, are up to you.